# Kong rate limit plugin to multiple services

Tags: api-gateway, rate-limiting, kong, kong-plugin

I'm using rate limiting plugin by Kong, I'm using the declarative mode with a config file like:

```
_format_version: "3.0"
_transform: true

services:
- name: service1
  url: https://example.com/api/endpoint1
  routes:
  - name: route1
    paths:
    - /path1
- name: service2
  url: https://example.com/api/endpoint2
  routes:
  - name: route2
    paths:
    - /path2

plugins:
- name: rate-limiting
  service: service1
  config:
    second: 5
    policy: local
    limit_by: service
- name: rate-limiting
  service: service2
  config:
    second: 5
    policy: local
    limit_by: service
```

for the rate limiting plugin I'm also using the attribute *limit_by: service*, because I want to rate limit all the requests arriving for that service not just by grouping by IP.

I have more or less 12 endpoints like the above conf. and for every endpoint I want to apply, up to now, the same rate limit, every time there is the need to add a block like that:

```
- name: rate-limiting
  service: serviceN
  config:
    second: 5
    policy: local
    limit_by: service
```

is it possible to specify a rate-limit for every service globally but still groupyng by the service name?

In the docs is written:
[image]

so it seems that every time we need to add the limit_by property otherwise it should group requests by IP.

Is there any way to do it without repeating every tie the plugin block?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to configure the plugin globally:

```
plugins:
- name: rate-limiting
  config:
    second: 5
    policy: local
    limit_by: service
```

The parameter `limit_by` configured to the value `service` defines the scope of the rate limit buckets by service id. There is no need to explicitly specify service names or ids.